# Python create xml file dynamically

Tags: python, xml, file, elementtree

i'm having trouble creating the xml file in python. My script at start loads a text file, read each line and check if the content contains a specific string, depending on it i want to create a tag  or  in the xml file.
For that i'm using the `ElementTree` module.

This the code

```
for line in myfile.read().splitlines():
    if 'EXTINF' in line:
        root = etree.Element("item")
        etree.SubElement(root, "title").text = line
    elif 'http' in line:
        etree.SubElement(root, "link").text = 'http:\\mysite.com\'
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('my\\path\\'+xml_file.xml)
```

The xml file contains only the last element iterated by for loop.

The output i would like is:

```
<item>
    <title> "my title" </title>
    <link> "http:\\mysite.com" </link>
</item>

<item>
    <title> "my title" </title>
    <link> "http:\\mysite.com" </link>
</item>

<item>
    <title> "my title" </title>
    <link> "http:\\mysite.com" </link>
</item>
```

What's wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the Element that you're assigning as the `root` variable each time you find `'EXTINF'`.

```
for line in myfile.read().splitlines():
    if 'EXTINF' in line:
        root = etree.Element("item") ## Creates a New Element called "item" with a variable name of "root"
        etree.SubElement(root, "title").text = line ## Creates a subelement called "title" to the current root variable
    elif 'http' in line:
        etree.SubElement(root, "link").text = 'http:\\mysite.com\' ## Creates a subelement called "title" to the current root variable

tree = etree.ElementTree(root) ## Create an ElementTree Object using the current root variable
tree.write('my\\path\\'+xml_file.xml)
```

So, obviously, you need to determine what the `root` variable should be (the lowest node in the XML tree) and then use a different variable for creating SubElements of `root`. Also, based on your original code and your desired output, I'm assuming that only items with titles should be outputted, so your code would need to reflect that *(specifically, in your code you only create the `item` element if 'EXTINF' is in the line, and none of your example outputs were lacking a title).*

```
root = etree.Element("root")
for line in myfile.read().splitlines():
    if 'EXTINF' in line:  ## If it has a title, then create an item.
        subelement = etree.SubElement(root,"item")
        etree.SubElement(subelement, "title").text = line
        if 'http' in line: ## Check if it has a link
            etree.SubElement(subelement, "link").text = 'http:\\mysite.com\'
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
```

If you're ok with items without titles:

```
for line in myfile.read().splitlines():
    subelement = etree.SubElement(root,"item") ## Always Create an item for each line
    if 'EXTINF' in line:
        etree.SubElement(subelement, "title").text = line
    if 'http' in line:
        etree.SubElement(subelement, "link").text = 'http:\\mysite.com\'
```

**EDIT:** Also, have you considered using `myfile.readlines()` instead of `myfile.read().splitlines()`?

Comment: Thanks it works. With your code the xml output contains also a "root" tag element, what if i would like to print only "title" and "link" tag without "root"? Is it possible?

Comment: Technically you can, but it's generally frowned upon, goes against standards defined by W3C, and is not supported out-of-the box with `etree` afaik. If it really is necessary to do so, then you would probably do so by iterating over the tree and calling `.tostring()` on all the subelements of `root`, then joining all those strings together and writing them to the file like any other string.